# Python: Merging Audio files that are in io.BytesIO form

Tags: python, audio, byte, response

I have a service that sends text to an external text to speech service that returns back audio in a response. This is how i access the audio:

```
res = requests.get(TTS_SERVICE_URL, params={"text":text_to_synth})
bytes_content = io.BytesIO(bytes(res.content))
audio = bytes_content.getvalue()
```

Now i would like to send multiple lines of text in different requests, and receive all the audio content in bytes, merge them into one audio and then display it, can anyone guide me as to how would i be able to merge the bytes_content into one audio byte stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work, posting the answer here if someone else faces the same problem, solved it as such

Read the bytes_content into a numpy array using soundfile:

```
data, samplerate = sf.read(bytes_content)
datas.append(data)
```

where datas is an empty array where each file to be concatenated is added

Then combine the files again

```
combined = np.concatenate(datas)
```

and convert back to a byte stream if needed

```
out = io.BytesIO()
sf.write(out, combined, samplerate=samplerate, format="wav")
```

I am pretty sure that this isn't the right way to do things, but this is what worked for me